# Exporting device manager to a txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file, device

I am trying to create a .bat file that when ran, it exports all of the devices from device manager to a .txt file.

Everything I have found hasn't been clear.

Just looking for some guidance on the command to execute this export. Thanks

Comment: What is the *device manager log* ?

Comment: just a document that displays all of the content from device manager

Answer (score 4):

All the content from the device manager? I believe this is what you are looking for. It does take a minute or two to run though and it is easier to read in .xml format, but here you go.

```
SET msinfo32="%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\MSInfo\msinfo32.exe"
%msinfo32% /nfo hwdres.nfo /categories +resources
rename hwdres.nfo hwdres.txt
```

The details listed under the "Components" section is what I believe you are after.

Comment: Thanks! Your command works perfectly on Windows 10. (The accepted answer does not.) Furthermore, I would recommend `http://www.lovettsoftware.com/downloads/xmlnotepad/readme.htm` which is a great XML viewer made by Microsoft. But easiest of all is to just double-click on the `hwdres.nfo` file and opening it in MsInfo, which lets you navigate everything naturally! :D

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a text report like this way in a bacth file :

```
@echo off
Title Generate a text report for Devices manager
Mode con cols=80 lines=3
cls & color 0A & echo.
Set "LogFile=DeviceManager.txt"
echo       Please wait a while we generate the report in %LogFile% .....
start /wait msinfo32 /report %LogFile%
start "" notepad %LogFile%
```

For more information about `msinfo32`

See here: http://ss64.com/nt/msinfo32.html

Comment: With console window and color setup! I really appreciate if contributors put the extra work in to make it nice. Well done.